# How Can I Connect With An IP Camera On My Lan But Different Subnet?

Tags: wireless-networking

My router died.

It used the 10.x.x.x address range.

ISP gave me a new router but it uses the 192.168.x.x address range for the LAN.

So I now have IP cameras in the 10.x.x.x range wirelessly connected to the LAN and not contactable.

i.e. they're not connected.  But I guess they're trying.

How can I connect with them to change their IP addresses?

I have taken one of them down and connected it with ethernet to my pc.

I can see traffic from it on Wireshark.  So I am certain of its address and certain it is alive.

But how to connect to it?

Or to those remaining up on the wifi?

Comment: You should be able to assign `10.X.X.X` with appropriate subnet mask in a machines TCP/IP settings with no gateway and then connect to them I think.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing to do is login to your new ISP provided device and change the LAN network address from 192.168.x.x to 10.x.x.x. If this is the same device providing wireless access then also change the wireless settings to match the original WiFi settings, including the exact SSID and encryption settings.

Now all the cameras should reconnect and work as usual. You would probably need to disconnect/reconnect other equipment or reboot it so that it connects using the new LAN settings.

Rarely, is it desirable to change “everything else” rather than changing the one device that is causing the problem.

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to connect it to the same network switch as the PC. The LAN-side ports on the 'router' usually serve as a switch. Wireless connections are usually bridged to the LAN-side ports and act as an extension to that switch. A direct connection *might* also work, but this depends on Auto MDI-X support — a switch is usually easier.

Once you have them connected in this fashion, the easiest way to proceed is to set up a static IP address on the PC. You'll want to put it in the same *subnet* as the camera, with the same subnet mask — this puts them on the same network so the PC will not try to send packets through its default gateway as it would do for non-LAN destinations.

If you know the specific subnet the camera is on (usually the last octet on a home network, e.g. `10.x.x.y` would be considered the `10.x.x.0/24` network, subnet mask of `255.255.255.0`) you just need to put the PC on any address on the network (e.g. the [randomly-chosen](https://xkcd.com/221/) `10.x.x.4`) and configure the subnet mask.

If you do not know the specific subnet, you should also be able to use the entire `10.0.0.0/8` space, with a subnet mask of `255.0.0.0`. Again, pick a random IP address from the range to assign to the PC. This should, in theory, tell the PC to attempt to communicate with any IP address from `10.0.0.1` to `10.255.255.254` via the local network.

Remember to change it back to what it was (probably automatically-assigned (DHCP)) when you're done, else you will no longer be able to connect to the internet.

Assuming you're using Windows, the configuration would look something like:

[image: Screenshot of IPv4 config in Windows]

If you do not know how to get to this dialog, see the "Set a Static IP Address in Windows 7, 8, or 10" section at https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/.